# Timeout waiting for network interface provisioning to complete

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

Does anyone know why an ECS Fargate task would fail with this error?
`Timeout waiting for network interface provisioning to complete`. I am running an ECS Fargate task using step functions. The IAM role for step function have access to the task def.The state machine code also looks good. The same step function worked fine before but i ran into this error just now. Want to know why this would happen? is it occasional?

Answer (score 5):

According to AWS support, intermittent failures of this nature are to be expected (with relatively low probability).

The recommendation was to set `retryAttempts > 1` to handle these situations.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if there are problems within AWS. You can view the Network Interfaces page on the EC2 console and you may see errors loading, which is an indication of API problems within EC2. You can also check [status.aws.amazon.com](https://status.aws.amazon.com/) to look for errors. Note that AWS can be slow to acknowledge problems there, so you may experience the errors before they update the status page!

Answer (score 0):

AWS support has a detailed post on [resolving network interface provision errors for ECS on Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-network-interface-errors/). Here's an excerpt from the same

> If the Fargate service tries to attach an elastic network interface to the underlying infrastructure that the task is meant to run on, then you can receive the following error message: "Timeout waiting for network interface provisioning to complete."

Fargate faces intermittent API issues usually while spinning up in Step functions and AWS Batch jobs. And as recommended in another answer you can update the `MaxAttempts` for retry in the definition.

```
"Retry": [
    {
        "MaxAttempts": 3,
    }
]
```

Additionally, reattempts can be automated with an exponential backoff and retry logic in [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-retrying-after-an-error).

Answer (score -1):

I was hitting the same issue until I switched over to fargate platform 1.4.0

It looks like there were some changes made to the networking side of things.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/aws-fargate-launches-platform-version-1-4/

The default version is currently still set at 1.3.0 so maybe give that a try and see if it fixes it for you.

Comment: I've still experienced this even with fargate 1.4.0.